# How to convert varchar to date only when it contains a valid date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for what I think to be a very useful information regarding SQL  Server Management Studio.

I have a table with a column of type `varchar` that stores dates, numbers, and strings.

Those dates are stored with the following format:

```
dd/mm/aaaa
```

I have a query that searchs form matching rows and one requirement is that the user must be able to seacrh between dates (period of time).

There is no mistery if I had just dates, I could use a query:

```
where convert(datetime,a.valor,103) between '01/01/2013' and '03/01/2013'
```

The problem is that this query fails when reach a row that the value is not a date.

What would be a efficient way to perform that query since there could be thousand of rows to search?

Comment: Would be nescessary to first perform a query excluding the dates, then  perform a second query for the dates, and for the last bind those 2 datasets in one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical answer is to add a WHERE clause:

```
WHERE ISDATE(a.valor) = 1
```

However this is problematic in your situation for a couple of reasons:

1. `ISDATE()` won't necessarily match the way you want depending on regional settings of the server, the user's language or dateformat options, etc. For example:

   ```
   SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
   SELECT ISDATE('13/01/2012'); -- 1

   SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
   SELECT ISDATE('13/01/2012'); -- 0
   ```
2. You can't really control that SQL Server will try and perform the `CONVERT` after the filter.

You can't even use subqueries or CTEs to try and separate the filter from the CONVERT because SQL Server *can* optimize the operations in the query in whatever order it deems more efficient.

For example, with a limited sample, you will probably find that this works okay:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

SELECT valor, valor_date FROM (
  SELECT valor, valor_date = CONVERT(DATE, 
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(valor) = 1 THEN valor ELSE NULL END, 103)
  FROM dbo.mytable
  WHERE ISDATE(valor) = 1
) AS sub WHERE valor_date BETWEEN '01/01/2012' AND '01/03/2012';
```

But I have seen cases with even this construct where SQL Server has tried to evaluate the filter first, leading to the same error you're currently getting.

---

A couple of safer workarounds:

---

Add a computed column, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytable ADD valor_date
  AS CONVERT(DATE, CASE WHEN ISDATE(valor) = 1 THEN valor 
    ELSE NULL END, 103);
```

To protect yourself from possible misinterpretations at runtime, you should specify dateformat before issuing a query that references the computed column, e.g.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT valor, valor_date FROM dbo.mytable WHERE ...;
```

---

Create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.myview
AS
  SELECT valor, valor_date = CONVERT(DATE, 
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(valor) = 1 THEN valor ELSE NULL END, 103)
  FROM dbo.mytable
  WHERE ISDATE(valor) = 1;
```

Again, you'll want to issue a `SET DATEFORMAT` when querying the view.

---

Use a temp table:

```
SELECT <cols>
INTO #foo
FROM dbo.mytable
WHERE ISDATE(valor) = 1;

SELECT <cols>, CONVERT(DATE, valor) FROM #foo WHERE ...;
```

You may still want to use `DATEFORMAT` to protect yourself from conflicts between `ISDATE` and user settings.

---

And no, you should *not* try to validate your strings as dates using string pattern matching as was suggested in another (now deleted) answer:

```
like '%__/%' or like '%/%'
```

You will have to have some pretty complex and heavy-handed validation there to handle all valid dates including leap years.

Answer (score -1):

You can compare the table to a table that just has dates in it. It is probably worth creating a permanent table with each day, but you can use a CTE (up to 32767 recursions which gets you to 1923):

```
create table tmpT ( val nvarchar(255) )
go

insert into tmpT values ('01/01/2012')
insert into tmpT values ('jellybeans')
insert into tmpT values ('21/11/2002')
insert into tmpT values ('ice cream')
insert into tmpT values ('30/08/2012')
go
;

with dates  (d) as (
    select d = cast('1/19/2013' as datetime) -- quick way to drop hh:mm:ss
    union all
    select dateadd(dd, -1, d)
    from dates where d > '01/01/1990'
)
select *
From tmpt 
join dates 
    on convert(varchar, dates.d, 103) = tmpt.val
where d between '01/01/2013' and '01/03/2013'
option (maxrecursion 32767) -- max value: select datediff(dd, -32767, getdate()) = 1923
```

ETA: Yes I am sitting in front of a sql 2005 so no `date` data type for me, but the concept remains the same.

Comment: Why not using a date table here?

Comment: Yes I would prefer a fixed table over a recursive CTE. See this recent blog series: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Comment: Agreed. Date/Int tables have many uses. I use them all the time. This solution I presented here does not require creating views, tables, or columns.