# Remove non-date values from a varchar column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In a table called customers I have a varchar2 column(financial_month).
This column is supposed to be a date column but since it is a varchar2 column and due to some wrong coding, there are many data which aren't in date format.
For eg: 0.15 has been stored in one record and many other wrong entries.

Now I want to eliminate all the wrong entries.
What process should I follow?
I have no clue whatsoever. I am not able to identify the wrong entries as well. The only thing I know is that there are more than 1000 wrong entries.

How to remove all the wrong entries from this column?

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure?

Comment: I think REGEXP_LIKE could be an option.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421534/how-to-convert-varchar-to-date-only-when-it-contains-a-valid-date and 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1106.htm#OLADM567

Comment: Can you identify the RIGHT entries?  In other words, create a format for the values you want to keep and null out all else (make a backup of the table first!).  What does good data look like?

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(financial_month, '^[0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{2}[.][0-9]{4}$')
```

to find rows with date values
(this is for date format DD.MM.YYYY or MM.DD.YYYY)

or more precise regexp

```
'^[0-3][0-9][.][0-1][0-9][.](19|20)[0-9]{2}$'
```

for DD.MM.YYYY format.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the format of the "financial months" must be MM/YYYY:

```
CREATE TABLE fm_t (fm VARCHAR2(30));

INSERT INTO fm_t VALUES ('01/2015');
INSERT INTO fm_t VALUES ('0.5');
INSERT INTO fm_t VALUES ('whatsever');
INSERT INTO fm_t VALUES ('02/2015');
SELECT * FROM fm_t;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fm_f(fm IN VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER IS
    d DATE;
BEGIN
    d := TO_DATE(fm, 'FMMM/YYYY');
    RETURN 1;
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RETURN 0;
END;
/

DELETE fm_t WHERE fm_f(fm) <> 1;
SELECT * FROM fm_t;

DROP FUNCTION fm_f;
DROP TABLE fm_t;
```